# How does Java implement "growable array" internally?

Tags: java, memory-management

I was reading documentation of the class Vector. It says:

> The Vector class implements a growable array of objects. Like an array, it contains components that can be accessed using an integer index. However, the size of a Vector can grow or shrink as needed to accommodate adding and removing items after the Vector has been created.

I was wondering how Java implements this "growable array" internally. When the array grows does it create a new (bigger) array and copy the contents of the old array into it, or is there any other mechanism (like realloc() in C)?

Comment: The duplicate is for `ArrayList`, but is equivalent to what is done in `Vector`, which you shouldn't be using.

Comment: If you install the JDK you can always see the source of public classes like Vector and see for yourself.

Comment: What prevents you of simply looking at the source code?

Comment: Note that C's `realloc` also works by allocating a bigger array and copying the contents.  It's not an "other mechanism".